# How to get a single output in SQL based on column values in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, relational-division

I have a query that returns a single column, STATUS which can have 2 distinct values SUCCESS and FAILED. So, sometimes it just returns SUCCESS or FAILURE or SUCCESS and FAILURE both. My requirement is to write a SQL query for snowflake to return 1 when the value is only SUCCESS and return 0 when the value is FAILURE or when both SUCCESS and FAILURE.

Comment: Can you share some sample data what could be your outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `conditional aggregation`. Feel to rewrite `iff` using `case` if you prefer so

**Scenario 1**

```
with cte(col)as

(select 'SUCCESS' union all
 select 'FAILURE')
 
 select min(iff(col='SUCCESS',1,0)) as status
 from cte;
```

**Scenario 2**

```
with cte(col)as

(select 'SUCCESS' union all
 select 'SUCCESS')
 
 select min(iff(col='SUCCESS',1,0)) as status
 from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CASE statment,

```
select CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = 'SUCESS' THEN 1
ELSE 0 END ret_value from 
values 
('SUCESS'), ('FAILURE'), ('SUCCESS and FAILURE');
```